# Unhandled exception not to log in appinsights

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-application-insights

I have a website in asp.net aspx. I have an HTTP handler. 
If there is any Unhandled exception, the application_error function in HTTP handler catches it. Then it also goes to Application_Error in global.ascx.

I have set up application insights.config to log all the exception in to Azure App insights. 
What I want is, some specific exception like maxURLsize, should not be logged in my Azure app insights.

I tried below things, but its not working.
1.  HttpContext.Current.Server.ClearError(); in Application_Error function
2. System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(false); in application_Error event in Http Handler.

Comment: Take a look at [ITelemetryProcessor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#filtering-itelemetryprocessor), which can filter out the unwanted telemetry data.

Comment: Thanks Ivan, it shows that we can skip the logging in app insights depending up on 400 or 500 response code. can you please advise how can we skip logging for a particular exception

Comment: Yes we can. But it requires that we need to know some properties of the particular exception, like response code, exception name etc. (or any of these properties we can uniquely identify the exception).

Comment: Hello, have you solved the issue as per the answer below?

Answer (score 1):

You can take use [ITelemetryProcessor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#filtering-itelemetryprocessor).

If you know the exception name, like `maxURLsize`, then in your custom telemetry processor class, you can use the code below(you can also combine other properties as per your need):

```
    public class MyErrorFilter: ITelemetryProcessor
    {
        private ITelemetryProcessor Next { get; set; }
        public MyErrorFilter(ITelemetryProcessor next)
        {
            this.Next = next;
        }
        public void Process(ITelemetry item)
        {           

            var exceptions = item as ExceptionTelemetry;

            if (exceptions != null && (exceptions.Exception.GetType().Name.ToLower() == "maxURLsize".ToLower()))
            {                
                return;
            }

            this.Next.Process(item);
        }
    }
```

then register it as per the doc mentioned above.