# handle the unhadlled exception in URL handdler and do not write it in APP insights

Tags: azure, exception, azure-application-insights

I have a site in ASPX and i have implemented a HTTPModule. 
when ever a un handled exception occurs, it goes to Application_Error event of HTTP module and then Application_Error event of global.ascx

I also have custom Error set to Off in web.config and have set up all 404 / 500 errors to go to error.aspx

I want all such exceptions to not to get logged in Application insights. How can i do that.

One more doubt, Having the HTTP Module Application_Error and the web.cofig CustomError Setting will act the same if i re direct it to error.aspx in Application_Error event ?

Comment: Hello, you asked the issue before, and that answer did not work for you?

Comment: Hi Ivan, my manager dont want me to filter the exception to log in to the App insights. but to catch the exception.-:(  the exceptions are getting catched using application_error event in HTP module. but at this stage, its getting logged in the app insights. which i dont want -:(

Comment: You don't want to use ITelemetry Processor to filter out the exception, right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unhandled exception not to log in appinsights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56945930/unhandled-exception-not-to-log-in-appinsights)

Comment: Yes Ivan. I dont want to filter the exception but to handle the exception.

Comment: @UmeshDeshmukh, not sure, but as far as I know, the only way to not log telemetry data to app insights is by using ITelemetry Processor.